# How i indent Second line of very long entry in the toc

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, alignment

I need to align the second line to the rigth, how can I do it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{mathptmx,mathpazo}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\newfontfamily\tocfont{Trajan Pro}

\titlecontents{part}[0em]{\vspace{1cm}}
{}
{\hfill\tocfont\Large\bfseries\thecontentslabel\enspace
}
{\tocfont\bfseries \Large | \contentspage}[\vspace{1cm}] 


\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\vspace{-4pt}}
{}
{\hfill\fontsize{6}{0.1}\selectfont\tocfont\bfseries
\contentslabel{0em}\enspace}
{\fontsize{6}{0.1}\selectfont\tocfont\bfseries | \contentspage}[\vspace{0cm}] 


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Discurso na reunião de comemoração do Soviete de Deputados do povo trabalhador e do Partido de Moscou e organizações públicas de Moscou}

\chapter{Discurso na reunião de celebração do Soviete de Deputados do Povo Trabalhador e do Partido e Organizações Públicas de Moscou}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this can be a starting point:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\newfontfamily\tocfont{Cochineal}%Trajan Pro

\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]
{\fontsize{6}{8}\selectfont
 \tocfont\bfseries
 \filleft
 \contentsmargin{1cm}}
{}
{\scshape}
{\rlap{\hskip1mm|}\contentspage}
[\vspace{0.1cm}] 


\begin{document}
 
 \tableofcontents
 
 \chapter{Discurso na reunião de comemoração do Soviete de Deputados do povo trabalhador e do Partido de Moscou e organizações públicas de Moscou}
 
 \chapter{Discurso na reunião de celebração do Soviete de Deputados do Povo Trabalhador e do Partido e Organizações Públicas de Moscou}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]